# R and Team Foundation Server

Tags: .net, r, tfs, data-analysis

We have 200+ in our IT, and I'm nominally a part of IT, but what I really do is BI. Our developers all use .NET and Visual Studio. I use R for data analysis (data analysis and predictive modeling). The only VCS allowed here is TFS. Can I use TFS for R source control without using VS? If so, are there any pointers for help or tutorials? Thanks.

Comment: TFS 2013 now [supports git](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bharry/archive/2013/06/19/enterprise-grade-git.aspx) and the git support in RStudio is superb.

Comment: Sorry, I tried. We're not allowed to use Git. It's TFS all the way or nothing at all.

Comment: So they are unwilling to let you use the capabilities baked into the Microsoft product? <insert comment about draconian IT shops> Have you tried the command-line TFS tools? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms253088.aspx They should work fine with R code.

Comment: Note: TFS is not source control. TFS provides two source control systems out of the box: TFVC for SVCS and Git for DVCS. So TFS is Git but Git is not TFVC.

Answer (score 1):

You on Windows? There's the the [Microsoft Visual Studio Team Foundation Server 2013 Power Tools](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/f017b10c-02b4-4d6d-9845-58a06545627f) that might help. It includes a Windows Explorer Shell Extension that can make using TFS outside of VS (and the command line) easier.

If you're not on Windows, the [Team Explorer Everywhere](http://www.visualstudio.com/products/team-explorer-everywhere-vs) might help.